# ggplot Bar graph, month is arranged alphabetically (ie Apr, Aug,Dec). I want it to be arranged in ascending order (ie Jan, Feb, Mar)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Data set:

```
Header| Header| Header
Month   A             B
Jan 2173.248       5433.12
Feb 2418.8252      5726.5076
Mar 2692.1532      6035.7396
Apr 2996.3648      6361.6696
May 3334.9558      6705.1996
Jun 3711.8048      7067.28
Jul 4131.2392      7448.914
Aug 4598.0682      7851.1554
Sep 5117.651       8275.1174
Oct 5695.9452      8721.9748
Nov 6339.586       9192.9618
Dec 7055.9588      9689.3808


u=dataset %>% gather(var, val, A:B)
ggplot(data=u,aes(x = Month, y = val, fill = var)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

I get the plot, but the months on x-axis are arranged "alphabetically". I want it rearranged in ascending order (i.e. Jan, Feb, Mar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have something like this:

```
dataset <- data.frame(Month = as.factor(c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun')),
                 A = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                 B = c(22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77))

u <- dataset %>% tidyr::gather(var, val, A:B)
```

You can change the order of factor levels by means of setting the order explicitly (respecting the order in the data frame):

```
u$Month <- factor(u$Month, levels = u$Month[order(u$val)])

ggplot(data=u,aes(x = Month, y = val, fill = var)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

Comment: I'm glad it works :-) if you find this answer useful, please consider accept it (it's the green tick to the left).

Answer (score 0):

You can manually define the order directly in ggplot:

```
ggplot(u, aes(x = Month, y = val, fill = var)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = dataset$Month)
```